# Php collect into same array which properties are owned same person

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have html elements like this:

```
<div id="show">
<p>1. <input name="name[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="surname[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="email[]" size="50" type="text"></p>

<p>2. <input name="name[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="surname[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="email[]" size="50" type="text"></p>

<p>3. <input name="name[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="surname[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="email[]" size="50" type="text"></p>

<p>4. <input name="name[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="surname[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="email[]" size="50" type="text"></p>

<p>5. <input name="name[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="surname[]" size="25" type="text">
<input name="email[]" size="50" type="text"></p>
</div>
```

And this is the output screen with dummy datas.[image]
When I serialize div#show and post it, dumping datas are like below:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'Hüsamettin' (length=11)
      1 => string 'Niyazi' (length=6)
      2 => string 'Abuzittin' (length=9)
      3 => string 'Haşmet' (length=7)
      4 => string 'Birben' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'Karadayürümez' (length=15)
      1 => string 'Tuzyemez' (length=8)
      2 => string 'Yerebasmaz' (length=10)
      3 => string 'Haşmetligil' (length=12)
      4 => string 'Eksiktim' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'husamettin@getmail.us' (length=21)
      1 => string 'tuzyemez@postmail.us' (length=20)
      2 => string 'abuzittin@setmail.us' (length=20)
      3 => string 'hasmetligil@mail.us' (length=19)
      4 => string 'birseneksiktim@mail.us' (length=22)
```

You see, first array collects names, second array collects surnames and third array collects email addresses. But I want to collect them like this:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Hüsamettin' (length=11)
      1 => string 'Karadayürümez' (length=15)
      2 => string 'husamettin@getmail.us' (length=21)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Niyazi' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Tuzyemez' (length=8)
      2 => string 'tuzyemez@postmail.us' (length=20)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Abuzittin' (length=9)
      1 => string 'Yerebasmaz' (length=10)
      2 => string 'abuzittin@setmail.us' (length=20)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Haşmet' (length=7)
      1 => string 'Haşmetligil' (length=12)
      2 => string 'hasmetligil@mail.us' (length=19)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Birben' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Eksiktim' (length=8)
      2 => string 'birseneksiktim@mail.us' (length=22)
```

This array type collects person's name, surname and email address like image above. Please could you help me, how do I create an array which collects someone's name, surname and email address from the first HTML elements?
Kind regards.

Comment: For -1, I wish you'd answer to my question and solve my problem, thus I can believe your sincerity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$grouped = array_map(null, $_POST['name'], $_POST['surname'], $_POST['email']);
```

Comment: brilliant; much faster than the way I was doing it (using a foreach loop)

Comment: Wow, the simpliest and the best! Thank you very much.